# Need explanation for jQuery .Show() effect flickering

Tags: jquery, css, show

Can someone please explain why flickering is occurring on this effect: http://codepen.io/theclarkofben/pen/xKhsd

I'm completely aware that the margin declared in the CSS is causing the issue to occur, but I do not understand the exact technical reasons for why it is happening.

I have found solutions to the issue, for example; create a parent container and apply the margin to that parent container instead. However, I do not understand why that solution works because I don't understand technically what was going wrong in the first place.

This post is the result of much searching online. I couldn't find an explanation, only solutions.

Thanks for your time.

```
$(function() {
// run the currently selected effect
function runEffect() {
  // get effect type from
  var selectedEffect = "clip";

  // most effect types need no options passed by default
  var options = {};
  // run the effect
  $( "#show_effect" ).show( selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
};

//callback function to bring a hidden box back
function callback() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $( "#show_effect:visible" ).removeAttr( "style" ).fadeOut();
  }, 1000 );
};

// set effect from select menu value
$( "#about_me_button" ).click(function() {
  runEffect();
});

$( "#show_effect" ).hide();
});
```

.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="about_me_button">About Me</button>
<div  id="show_effect" class="about_me">
  <p>Quis vivendum ei vim, ut alia essent persequeris ius. Et sed diam harum consul, ut usu admodum appareat. In odio tale per, vel eu semper feugait vituperatoribus. Accumsan deseruisse eos te, vix nibh omnis ei.Quis vivendum ei vim, ut alia essent persequeris ius. Et sed diam harum consul, ut usu admodum appareat. In odio tale per, vel eu semper feugait vituperatoribus. Accumsan deseruisse eos te, vix nibh omnis ei.Quis vivendum ei vim, ut alia essent persequeris ius. Et sed diam harum consul, ut usu admodum appareat. In odio tale per, vel eu semper feugait vituperatoribus. Accumsan deseruisse eos te, vix nibh omnis ei.Quis vivendum ei vim, ut alia essent persequeris ius. Et sed diam harum consul, ut usu admodum appareat. In odio tale per, vel eu semper feugait vituperatoribus.</p>
</div>
```

.

```
.about_me {
  width: 600px;
  height: 225px;
  margin-right: -300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the .show() function runs, the .about_me div gets wrapped in a temporary wrapper `<div class="ui-effects-wrapper">`. This takes its height and width from the existing .about_me div. I imagine the negative margin right is causing the width of this new wrapper div to be 300px instead of the original 600px. Additionally the wrapper div has overflow set to hidden. So as content loads, it is cut off. Then when the show animation is complete, the temporary div is removed so you see the full paragraph.

See attached screenshot of code during the show animation.

[image: screenshot of code during show animation]